# Is there a name for the "a"/"an" exceptions?

Tags: terminology

"A person" or "an ornament" are normal instances of 'A' being followed by consonants or vowels. However the rule seems to have exceptions when a word sounds like it starts with the opposite, such as "an hour" or "a url" (when url is pronounced letter by letter).

Is there a name for this kind of exception?

Comment: These are *not* exceptions. They *all* follow the exact same rule: "an" before a vowel *sound*, "a" otherwise. "Hour" begins with a vowel *sound*, hence "an". "URL" does not begin with a vowel *sound*, thus "a". This has been [covered to death](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/152?sort=votes) on this site. We even have a dedicated question specifically for "an hour", and one specifically about "a URL". We also have [a blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) covering all bases. Please do search the site before asking. Thank you.

Comment: These questions and blog post all seem to be about usage. This question is not about when to use one over the other. I'm asking about a name for this "exception" to the rule. It turns out it's less of an exception and more of a misquoted rule by my teachers.

Comment: The 'exceptions' are 'an historical', and one or two others, where the h is aspirated but _an_ is perversely used. Note that a few people do _not_ aspirate 'historical', so this would not constitute an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider them exceptions if you understand that the a/an rule depends on phonetics instead of spelling. If the letter following a/an has a vowel *sound* (which it does with an unsounded "h"), use "an". URL is a bit trickier, because the "u" is actually a phonetic glide that acts as a consonant (and should be used with "a"). I would agree there are exceptions (which have no name as far as I know), but these are not on that list.